# Programa de Ahorcado en Qt

Tags: c

¿Me podrían ayudar y decirme que está mal en el siguiente ejercicio y como mejorarlo?

El enunciado es:

> En este ejercicio programaremos el juego del ahorcado simplificado. Al comenzar le pediremos al primer jugador la palabra secreta y a continuación borraremos la pantalla con el comando system(“cls”); (para que el segundo jugador no la vea).
>
> El segundo jugador tendrá tres oportunidades para dar con la palabra. Si en alguno de los tres intentos acierta le felicitaremos y el programa terminará. Si falla los tres intentos le diremos que ha perdido y mostraremos la palabra oculta. En cada intento le daremos una pista al usuario: en el primer intento mostraremos la primera letra de la cadena, en el segundo intento la última y en el tercero la letra central.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void){

    char pj1[50],pa[50],pb[50],pc[50];
    printf("Ha comenzado el juego del ahorcado\n");
    printf ("jugador 1, introduzca la palabra secreta:");
    scanf("%s",pj1);
    system("cls");
    printf("Jugador 2,solo tienes 3 intentos\n");
    printf("Primer intento:(Pista)Empieza por la letra %c:",pj1[0]);
    scanf("%s",pa);

    int a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
    int n=strlen(pj1);

    if( a!=0)
    {
      printf("Segundo intento:(Pista)Termina por la letra %c:",pj1[n-1]);
      scanf("%s",pa);

      a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
    }

    if( a!=0)
    {
      printf("Tercer intento:(Pista)Contiene la letra %c:",pj1[(n-1)/2]);
      scanf("%s",pa);

      a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
    }

    if( pa==0){printf("¡Felicidades, acertaste\n");
    }else{printf("Lo siento, has perdido. La palabra era %s\n",pj1);}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ésta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Qt, es más está usando C, no C++.

Comment: @ArielM. Date cuenta que la pregunta tiene 2 años... viendo que isabel tiene 3 puntitos yo te apostaría a que no es un miembro activo de la comunidad en estos momentos...

Comment: @ArielM. Por otro lado nota que el código compila perfectamente en C++. Lo que te dice la etiqueta es que para responder puedes usar características propias de c++

Comment: La respuesta es útil, un moderador con más puntos puede cambiar el título.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a=strcmp(pj1,pa);

printf("Primer intento:(Pista)Empieza por la letra %c:",pj1[0]);
scanf("%s",pa);
```

En la primera línea comparas lo que aún **no** ha introducido el usuario con la palabra a encontrar y en la tercera línea le pides la palabra al usuario. Lo estás haciendo al revés. Primero pide la palabra al usuario y después compara esa palabra. Así:

```
printf("Primer intento:(Pista)Empieza por la letra %c:",pj1[0]);
scanf("%s",pa);

int a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
```

Por otro lado, no le vas a pedir al jugador una segunda palabra si ha acertado a la primera. Y por la misma regla no vas a pedirle una tercera si la ha acertado a la segunda o la primera. Esto quiere decir que no hace falta una variable para cada palabra:

```
printf("Primer intento:(Pista)Empieza por la letra %c:",pj1[0]);
scanf("%s",pa);

int a=strcmp(pj1,pa);

if( a!=0)
{
  printf("Segundo intento:");
  scanf("%s",pa); // podemos sobreescribir pa tranquilamente

  a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
}

if( a!=0)
{
  printf("Tercer intento:");
  scanf("%s",pa); // podemos sobreescribir pa tranquilamente

  a=strcmp(pj1,pa);
}

if( a==0)
  // Ha acertado la palabra
else
  // No ha acertado la palabra tras tres intentos
```

Más cosillas:

```
printf("Segundo intento:(Pista)Termina por la letra %c:",pj1[-1]);
```

Los vectores van desde el índice 0 hasta n-1, siendo *n* el tamaño del vector. -1 no es un valor válido porque está fuera del rango (0,n-1). Para recuperar el último carácter de una cadena tienes que localizar el final de la misma (recuerda que las cadenas terminan siempre con el caracter nulo `\0`. Esto lo puedes conseguir usando `strlen()` (que te dice la longitud de la cadena) o iterando el vector hasta encontrar el final de la cadena:

```
int len = strlen(pj1);
char c=pj1[len-1];

int pos=0;
for(; pj[pos+1]!='\0'; ++pos);
char c=pj1[pos];
```

Y lo mismo te pasa con el caracter de la mitad de la cadena... A ver si ese eres capaz de sacarlo tu sola.

Pd.: Si edito varias veces es porque estoy desde el móvil

Comment: oki me podrias explicar que es la exclamación de a? y... en el segundo intento tengo que poner como pista que la última letra es tal y en el tercer intento que la letra de enmedio es tal eso como lo hago?

Comment: Estaba editando la pregunta mientras ponías el comentario

Comment: `!=` significa _distinto_. Ese if se ejecutará si el valor en `a` es distinto a 0

Comment: gracias creo que ya me sale ^^

Comment: vale no. me esta dando errores y no se porque

Comment: he reeditado la pregunta a ver que ves que este mal

Comment: @Isabel El código que puse tenía una errata... Cosas de escribir desde el móvil. Si no das detalles del error es complicado ayudar. Eso sí hazte a la idea de que te toca ponerte las pilas para aprender la base de la programación en C

Comment: aquí colaborando : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm :D

Comment: @Isabel. Al editar la pregunta intenta no sobreescribir lo que ya tenías (salvo que sea para corregir errores). si no las respuestas dejan de ser válidas. En cuanto a tu error, sustituye `pa` por `a` en las comparaciones

Comment: yaaaa por fiiin uffff

Comment: muchiiiiiiiiisimas gracias. no sabes cuantas semanas llevaba ya jajaja ufff

Comment: y sip me tengo que poner muy fuertemente jajaja pero esque este es el tercer ejercicio que hago no esperaba demasiado jajajaja

Comment: Me alegro. Eso sí, ponte las pilas que en el examen no tendrás acceso a este foro

Comment: Ésta respuesta está mal ya que preguntaron por una solución en Qt, no en C. O se arregla la pregunta o se desaprueba la respuesta.

Comment: @ArielM. Puedes comprobar que el código compila perfectamente en Qt. Guste o no la librería estándar (que es lo que estaba usando @isabel), va a esta disponible aún compilando con Qt.

Comment: @ArielM. Por otro lado la respuesta está basada en el código de la pregunta. No es menester reescribir el código de cero sino solucionar el problema planteado. Si lo ves conveniente, elabora una respuesta usando únicamente Qt

Comment: Dado que la respuesta es en C, el título de la pregunta debe cambiar a "C"

Comment: @ArielM. La respuesta compila perfectamente en c++, de eso puedes estar segura. Si usa exclusivamente elementos comunes con C es porque rehacerla en c++ desvirtuaba el origen del problema... pero el código compila en c++, luego la crítica no se termina de sostener

Comment: @ArielM. En cualquier caso, repito, la pregunta tiene 2 años de antigüedad y las políticas actuales de [es.so] no tiene por qué ser las mismas que hace dos años... y no tiene sentido modificar todas las preguntas antiguas que no casen con la política actual

Comment: @ArielM. Si aun así no te termino de convencer, comenta el tema en meta a ver que te cuentan

Comment: Qt es un framework de C++ y es una mala práctica compilar C con compilador C++. La respuesta no es correcta salvo que lo haga con Qt o que cambie el título.

Comment: Peor cuando la persona está estudiando para un exámen. Si su profesor se pone estricto le pedirá seguir las reglas como es, es decir: C++ y Qt

Comment: @ArielM. Te repito. La pregunta **tiene 2 años**. Si te vas a poner estricta hazlo con preguntas nuevas, como he hecho yo en más de una ocasión. Pero con preguntas viejas no tiene sentido porque, como ya he dicho, las políticas cambian con el tiempo y ello invalida muchas preguntas antiguas... ¿las cambiamos todas? ¿las borramos? No voy a responder mas a este tema. Si tienes dudas ve a meta y se hará lo que diga la comunidad

Comment: @ArielM. ¿y por qué es una mala práctica? Acaso ese codigo no es c++ valido? Con el estándar en la mano ya te aviso que el código es c++ ya que cumple todas las reglas previstas en este lenguaje. Otra cosa es, como he dicho, que sea recomendable usar las clases propias de c++... pero ese es otro dilema diferente

Comment: No es ningún dilema, y StackOverflow se trata de buenas prácticas no de hacer cosas sucias que sean mínimamente válidas. Pero de que es incorrecto, lo es, porque C no es C++ y C tampoco es Qt como indica la pregunta. Si se acepta la respuesta debería cambiarse el título, como mencioné antes. Si tienes el estándar en la mano C++17 (ISO/IEC 14882:2017) podrás leer que scanf fue declarada 'deprecated' hace como 10 años y la única manera de compilar sin errores es con un compilador antiguo o con banderas especiales de compilación

Comment: @ArielM. No es *deprecated* sino *unsafe*, que no es lo mismo. De la misma manera que usarlo genera *warnings* y no errores. A lo demás no voy a responder viendo que tu única respuesta se hizo por partes cuando lo suyo según la comunidad habría sido tirar de comentarios hasta tener la pregunta bien atada. No se por qué la has tomado con una pregunta tan antigua pero, en serio, vete a meta y hablalo allí  a ver qué te cuentan