# programa qt: ahorcado

Tags: c++

Alguien me puede ayudar con este ejercicio? acabo de empezar clases de programacion y este ejercicio no me sale.

En este ejercicio programaremos el juego del ahorcado un poco más avanzado que en la práctica  anterior. Al  comenzar  le  pediremos  al  primer  jugador  la  palabra  secreta  y  a continuación  borraremos  la  pantalla  con  el  comando  system(“cls”);  (para  que  el segundo jugador no la vea). El segundo jugador tendrá cinco oportunidades para dar con la  palabra.  Si  en  alguno  de  los cinco intentos  acierta  le  felicitaremos  y  el  programa terminará. Si falla los cinco intentos le diremos que ha perdido y mostraremos la palabra oculta. A modo de pista, en cada intento mostrarem
os la palabra oculta al usuario, pero con las  letras desordenadas aleatoriamente. Cada  vez  que  terminemos  una  partida,  el programa  nos  preguntará si  queremos  volver  a  jugar.

NOTA:  para  desordenar  aleatoriamente  la  palabra,  debes  utilizar números  aleatorios que se obtienen con la función rand. Por ejemplo, para elegir un número aleatorio del 0 al  9  sería: 
int  num  =  rand()%10;
Para  desordenar  la  palabra,  elige  dos  posiciones aleatorias  e  intercambia  los  caracteres  de  las  mismas.  Repite  esa  operación n*n
veces (siendo n la longitud de la palabra) y tendrás la palabra desordenada.

a ver empece con esto pero no se si empece bien... sinceramente ni se si esta bien ni se continuar.

```
int main(void){ 
char pj1[50],pa[50]; 
printf("Ha comenzado el juego del ahorcado\n"); 
printf ("jugador 1, introduzca la palabra secreta:"); 
scanf("%s",pj1); s
ystem("cls"); 
printf("Jugador 2,solo tienes 5 intentos\n"); 
char pj1=n; int pj1 = rand(n*n)%n; 
printf("Intento 1 de 5:%c",pj1); 
scanf("%s",pa);
```

Comment: Por favor, añade al menos algo de código que hayas intentado. Stackoverflow no es una comunidad "para que te hagan los deberes".

Comment: a ver empece con esto pero no se si empece bien... sinceramente ni se si esta bien ni se continuar

Comment: int main(void){

    char pj1[50],pa[50];
    printf("Ha comenzado el juego del ahorcado\n");
    printf ("jugador 1, introduzca la palabra secreta:");
    scanf("%s",pj1);
    system("cls");
    printf("Jugador 2,solo tienes 5 intentos\n");

    char pj1=n;
    int pj1 = rand(n*n)%n;
    printf("Intento 1 de 5:%c",pj1);
    scanf("%s",pa);

Comment: no hace falta que me expliqueis entero. quiero saber si la primera parte(pedir la palabra, hacerla desaparecer esta bien) y ya que me explique como hacer el primer intento (eso de hacer que aparezca la palabra con las letras mezcladas que es lo que no se hacer) supongo que entonces ya me costara menos.

Comment: Te pediría que añadieras tu código a la pregunta. De esta manera, queda mucho más claro (con el código que has puesto en el comentario) tu problema y es mucho más fácil que la gente vea toda la información una sola vez.

Comment: ¿No serás compañera de clase de [isabel](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18415/isabel) (¡o la misma!) *guiño guiño* que [hizo una pregunta sobre el mismo ejercicio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27643/programa-de-ahorcado-en-qt)?. La pregunta anterior era de C, ahora C++ ¿habéis cambiado de lenguaje?

Comment: soy la misma... soy una inutil con programacion jajajaja. vuelvo a necesitar ayuda y no solo con este pero bueno. con este de momento me parece que esta bien. no es el mismo. es parecido. tengo porblemas sobre todo con lo de desordenar las letras de la palabra